search for multiple strings in multiple columns in ORACLE SQL
I have one database table with person information (id, fname, lname, street, city...).
I want to search with multiple strings in all the columns, for e.g., my search string is mainstreet John Doe.
Now, I want to create a select query (Oracle SQL), which searches all strings in all columns.



fname
lname
street
city
return from select




John
Doe
mainstreet
New York
yes


John
Doe
street
New York
no


Doe
John
mainstreet
New York
yes


mainstreet
John
doe
New York
yes



Is there a way in Oracle SQL to create such a query?

You might want to look at Oracle Text.

For the searchstring "street John Doe" you would only return row #2, correct?

correct, only row #2

You can break up your search string and search the concatenated columns for each one:
select *
  from (select p.*,
               '|'||fname||'|'||lname||'|'||street||'|'||city||'|' searchlist
          from person)
 where searchlist like '%|mainstreet|%
   and searchlist like '%|John|%
   and searchlist like '%|Doe|%

It won't perform great a large volumes (because not able to use a index), but at a reasonably modest table size would be the easiest.
If you wanted speed at a high volume, you'd be best off creating a child table with each word (fname, lname, street, city, etc.) which you can then index normally and search with an equality predicate.

thanks, thats the solution for my problem

Given the sample data:
CREATE TABLE person (fname, lname, street, city, return_from_select ) AS
SELECT 'John',       'Doe',  'mainstreet', 'New York', 'yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',       'Doe',  'street',     'New York', 'no'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Doe',        'John', 'mainstreet', 'New York', 'yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'mainstreet', 'John', 'doe',        'New York', 'yes' FROM DUAL;

You should be able to create an Oracle Text multi-column index:
BEGIN
  ctx_ddl.create_preference('person_lexer', 'BASIC_LEXER');  
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('person_lexer', 'mixed_case', 'NO'); 

  ctx_ddl.create_preference('person_datastore', 'MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE'); 
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute(
    'person_datastore',
    'columns',
    'fname, lname, street, city'
  ); 
END;
/

CREATE INDEX person_idx
  ON person (fname) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
  PARAMETERS ('datastore person_datastore lexer person_lexer');

Then use the query:
SELECT *
FROM   person
WHERE  CONTAINS(fname, 'mainstreet AND John AND Doe') > 1

or:
SELECT *
FROM   person
WHERE  CONTAINS(
         fname,
         REPLACE('mainstreet John Doe', ' ', ' AND ')
       ) > 1;

or
SELECT *
FROM   person
WHERE  CONTAINS(
         fname,
         REGEXP_REPLACE('mainstreet John Doe', '\s+', ' AND ')
       ) > 1;

Which all output:



FNAME
LNAME
STREET
CITY
RETURN_FROM_SELECT




John
Doe
mainstreet
New York
yes


Doe
John
mainstreet
New York
yes


mainstreet
John
doe
New York
yes



